# Зачем докеризация asp.net core создаёт лишнюю директорию?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker, asp.net-core-mvc

Пробую упаковать приложение asp.net core в контейнер докер [по статье](https://habr.com/en/company/microsoft/blog/435914/), всё получается, но есть непонятный момент.

> Начальная конфигурация для .NET Core 2.0 не позволит вам сразу
>   построить образ с помощью команды docker build. Она настроена на то,
>   что будет запущен файл docker-compose из директории уровнем выше. Для
>   того чтобы построение происходило успешно Dockerfile можно привести к
>   подобному виду:
>
> Все что я сделал, это убрал лишнюю директорию DockerServiceDemo.

Я контейнеризировал проект 2.2, у меня была другая структура каталогов -- но тем не менее, генератор студии мне тоже создал Dockerfile с такой же лишней структурой и мне тоже пришлось убирать из кода эту лишнюю директорию.

Не ахти какие действия, но ведь какая-то в этом логика закладывывалась разработчиками майкрософт?

Зачем же это было нужно вообще? Зачем запускать docker-compose из директории уровнем выше?

Comment: Она не лишняя, просто стандартная раскладка папок ориентирована именно на compose + наличие нескольких проектов в решении. Compos подразумевает поддержку нескольких сервисов в рамках одного решения, поэтому его файл лежит выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose - оркестратор, и рассчитан на поддержку нескольких сервисов. Соответственно, он может ссылаться на несколько проектов, и на несколько docker-файлов.

Попробуйте создать два проекта в одном решении и вызвать Add Container Orchestrator Support / Docker Compose для обоих. Получите следующую раскладку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в качестве контекста у обоих проектов будет использоваться папка решения:

```
services:
  app1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App1/Dockerfile

  app2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App2/Dockerfile
```

т.к. они могут зависеть от других проектов из решения, и исходники этих проектов должны быть доступны в build-контейнере.